# What does "put out" mean in the following context?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

What does "put out" mean in the following context?

> I, myself, who find sundown something of a surprise every evening,
>   have been pursued by foreign journalists asking what the pandemic will
>   mean for the American presidential election, populism, the prospects
>   of socialism, race relations, economic growth, higher education, New
>   York City politics and more. And they seem awfully **put out** when I
>   say I have no idea.

Comment: From Collins COBUILD: "If you feel put out, you feel rather annoyed or upset. "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Merriam-Webster's [definition #5B](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/putout) for the phrase 'put out' fits this context:

> Annoy, irritate

The journalists are annoyed/irritated by the writer's inability to answer their questions.

Comment: Hello, 770. This is too basic for ELU, being a question most pupils in the first two years of secondary school would be expected to know the answer to. Also, as Kate indicates, basic research would provide the answer.

Comment: A lot of folks here will be put out that you didn't do proper research.

Answer (score -1):

***Put out*** (*adjective*) with the sense of (especially of a person) 'disgruntled, annoyed, unhappy,fed up’ has been in use since at least 1796:

F. Burney Camilla V. x. xiv. 542   *I can't say but what I'm a little put out, that Indiana should forget poor Mrs. Margland.* (OED)

It seems reasonable to suppose that this sense may have had it's origin in the phrase

***'Put your nose out of joint'***

used by Barnaby Rich in *His Farewell to Militarie Profession*  (1581) with the sense of 'hurt your feelings' or 'upset your plans'.

See also [Origin of "nose out of joint"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/167259/origin-of-nose-out-of-joint)